# ScrollVIew Scrolls automacally when i update something in it

Tags: react-native, scrollview

i'm using ScrollView for my react native project and my scrollView is scrolling up whenever i update something in its children and  i really don't want that
can you please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code:

```
<ScrollView >
                <View style={styles.containerParent} >
                    <Text style={styles.textHorodatage} >Services</Text>
                    <View style={styles.touchable} >
                        <Block>
                            <View>
                                <FontAwesome name="paint-brush" size={22} color={Couleurs.PrimaryHomme} style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginVertical: 5 }} />
                                <FlatList
                                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                                    scrollEnabled={false}
                                    contentContainerStyle={{
                                        marginHorizontal: 10,
                                    }}
                                    refreshing={isFetching}
                                    data={
                                        // route.params==undefined?
                                        ChoixService
                                        // :route.params[1].details
                                    }
                                    renderItem={(item) => {
                                        return <CartePanier item={item.item} />;
                                    }}
                                />
                                <View style={{ justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexDirection: 'row' }} >
                                    <View>
                                        <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', fontFamily: 'poppins-bold', color: Couleurs.PrimaryFemme, marginBottom: -10, fontSize: 15 }} >Estimation durée:</Text>
                                        <Text style={styles.text} >{toHoursAndMinutes(TotalEstimation)}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View>
                                        <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', fontFamily: 'poppins-bold', color: Couleurs.PrimaryFemme, marginBottom: -10, fontSize: 15 }} >Total:</Text>
                                        <Text style={styles.text} >{
                                            // route.params != undefined ?  PrixTotalParams :
                                            PrixTotal}Ar
                                        </Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                                <LinearGradient
                                    colors={[Couleurs.PrimaryHomme, "#F0FFFF"]}
                                    start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
                                    end={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                                    locations={[0.4, 1]}
                                    style={styles.gradient}>

                                    <Button icon={() => <Ionicons name={route.params == undefined ? "add-circle" : "pencil-sharp"} size={25} color={Couleurs.Blanc} style={{ right: -4 }} />}
                                        onPress={() => setopenService(!openService)} mode='contained' color='transparent' labelStyle={styles.labelStyle} style={styles.buttonHorodatage} >
                                        {route.params == undefined ? "Ajouter" : "Modifier"}
                                    </Button>
                                </LinearGradient>
                            </View>
                        </Block>
                    </View>
                    {
                        openService &&
                        <>
                            <Carousel
                                data={categories}
                                renderItem={CarteCategory}
                                sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH / 1.05}
                                itemWidth={150}
                                loop={true}
                                layout={"default"}
                                firstItem={indexUseProth}
                                containerCustomStyle={{ marginVertical: 5, left: 1.3 }}
                            />
                        </>
                    }
                </View>
                <View>

                </View>
                <View style={styles.containerParent} >
                    <Text style={styles.textHorodatage} > Horodatage du rendez-vous </Text>
                    <View style={styles.containerHorodatage}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setOpenDate(true)} style={styles.touchable} >
                            <FontAwesome5 name="calendar-day" size={20} color={Couleurs.PrimaryHomme} style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} />
                            <Text style={styles.text}>
                                {getFormatedDate(date, "DD MMMM YYYY")}
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        {/* } */}
                        {openDate && <DatePicker
                            options={{
                                backgroundColor: Couleurs.Blanc,
                                textHeaderColor: Couleurs.PrimaryHomme,
                                textSecondaryColor: Couleurs.PrimaryFemme,
                                mainColor: Couleurs.PrimaryHomme,
                                defaultFont: 'montserrat-bold',
                                headerFont: 'montserrat-bold',
                                headerAnimationDistance: 50,
                                daysAnimationDistance: 300
                            }}
                            mode="calendar"
                            style={styles.datePicker}
                            selected={date}
                            onDateChange={HandleDate}
                            locale='fr'
                        />}
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setopenTime(true)} style={styles.touchable} >
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="clock" size={25} color={Couleurs.PrimaryHomme} style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} />
                            <Text style={styles.text}>
                                {time}
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    {
                        openTime
                        &&
                        <DatePicker
                            options={{
                                backgroundColor: Couleurs.Blanc,
                                textHeaderColor: '#FFA25B',
                                textDefaultColor: Couleurs.PrimaryFemme,
                                selectedTextColor: '#fff',
                                mainColor: Couleurs.PrimaryHomme,
                                textSecondaryColor: '#D6C7A1',
                                defaultFont: 'montserrat-bold',
                                headerFont: 'montserrat-bold',
                            }}
                            mode="time"
                            style={styles.datePicker}
                            minuteInterval={30}
                            onTimeChange={HandleTime}

                        />}

                </View>
                <Toast config={toastConfig} />
                <View style={styles.containerParent} >
                    <Text style={styles.textHorodatage} >Salon</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setOpenSalonCaroussel(!openSalonCaroussel)} style={styles.touchable} >
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home-city" size={25} color={Couleurs.PrimaryHomme} style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginVertical: 5 }} />
                        <Text style={styles.textSalon} >
                            {selectedSalon}
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {openSalonCaroussel &&
                        <>
                            <Text style={styles.textHorodatage} >Glissez et Cliquez votre choix</Text>
                            <Carousel
                                data={salon}
                                renderItem={CarteSalon}
                                sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH / 1.042}
                                itemWidth={170}
                                loop={true}
                                layout={"default"}
                                firstItem={indexUse}
                                autoplayDelay={2000}
                                autoplayInterval={9000}
                                onSnapToItem={(slideIndex: number) => {
                                    setindexUse(slideIndex)
                                }
                                }
                            />
                        </>
                    }
                </View>
                <View style={styles.containerParent} >
                    <Text style={styles.textHorodatage} >Esthéticien(ne)</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setopenProthCaroussel(true)} style={styles.touchable} >
                        <Ionicons name="ios-person-circle-sharp" size={35} color={Couleurs.PrimaryHomme} style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} />
                        <CarteProthesiste item={selectionProth} style={{ alignSelf: 'center', top: -15 }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {openProthCaroussel &&
                        <>
                            <Text style={styles.textHorodatage} >Glissez et Cliquez votre choix</Text>
                            <Carousel
                                data={prothesiste}
                                renderItem={CarteProthesiste}
                                sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH / 1.042}
                                itemWidth={170}
                                layout={"default"}
                                firstItem={indexUseProth}
                                autoplayDelay={2000}
                                autoplayInterval={9000}
                                onSnapToItem={(slideIndex: number) => {
                                    setindexUseProth(slideIndex)
                                }
                                }
                            />
                        </>
                    }
                </View>
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', fontFamily: 'poppins-bold', color: Couleurs.PrimaryFemme, marginBottom: -10, fontSize: 15 }} >Total:</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text} >{
                    // route.params != undefined ?  PrixTotalParams :
                    PrixTotal}Ar
                </Text>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', width: '100%' }} >
                    <Button onPress={() => {
                        route.params == undefined
                            ?
                            this.goBack()
                            :
                            SetShowAlert(true)
                    }} mode='contained' style={{ width: 150, borderColor: Couleurs.PrimaryHomme, borderWidth: 1, height: 40, top: 5, borderRadius: 12 }} color={Couleurs.Blanc} labelStyle={[styles.labelStyle, { color: Couleurs.PrimaryHomme }]} >
                        {route.params != undefined ? "Annuler" : "Retour"}
                    </Button>
                    <LinearGradient
                        colors={[Couleurs.PrimaryHomme, "#F0FFFF"]}
                        start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
                        end={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                        locations={[0.4, 1]}
                        style={styles.gradient2}>
                        <Button
                            // icon={()=> <FontAwesome5 name="check" size={23} color={Couleurs.Blanc} style={{alignSelf:'center'}}/>}
                            labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
                            theme={{ animation: { scale: 2 } }}
                            onPress={() => {
                                !time || !date || !selectedSalon || selectionProth.length == 0 || ChoixService.length == 0
                                    ?
                                    Toast.show({
                                        type: 'info',
                                        text1: 'Information incomplete',
                                        text2: openDate || openProthCaroussel || openSalonCaroussel || openService || openTime ? 'completez votre selection' : `choisissez ${!date ? 'une date' : !time ? 'une heure' : !selectedSalon ? 'le salon' : selectionProth.length == 0 ? "l'éstheticien(ne)" : ChoixService.length == 0 ? 'le service' : null}`,
                                        visibilityTime: 5000,
                                        autoHide: true,
                                        position: 'bottom',
                                        bottomOffset: 130,
                                        onPress: () => { Toast.hide() }
                                    })
                                    : route.params != undefined && TotalPrixParams < PrixTotal ?
                                        SetShowAlert(true)
                                        : route.params != undefined && TotalPrixParams == PrixTotal ?
                                            [navigation.navigate('Réservations'), route.params = undefined] :
                                            [ navigation.navigate('PayementGeneral'),,setDate(''), setTime(''), setSelectedSalon(''), setSelectionProth([]), viderCHoixService(), setOpenRDV(!openRVD)]

                            }}
                            mode='contained' color='transparent' style={{ width: '100%', borderRadius: 20 }}  >
                            {route.params != undefined ? "  Modifier  " : "  Réserver  "}
                        </Button>
                    </LinearGradient>
                </View>
                {
                    route.params != undefined
                        ?
                        <Button onPress={() => {
                            setshowAlertAnnulation(true)
                        }}
                            mode='contained' uppercase={false} style={{ width: 320, borderColor: Couleurs.PrimaryFemme, borderWidth: 1, height: 40, top: 5, borderRadius: 12, alignSelf: 'center', }} color={Couleurs.Blanc} labelStyle={[styles.labelStyle, { color: Couleurs.PrimaryFemme }]} >
                            Annuler le Rendez-vous
                        </Button>
                        :
                        null}
                <View style={{ marginVertical: 100 }} />
            </ScrollView>
```